# Resources on Moore and Mealy Machines

Tags: finite-automata

I was studying about Moore and Mealy machines but having hard time connecting with them because 1) they are different from typical normal machines.what is the need of "output" and 2) My text book doesn't cover it (Michael Sipser). What are the application for Moore and Mealy machines? I would like some resources.

Comment: Did you try on Wikipedia?

Comment: If you want to see nice applications, finite transducers (Moore/Mealy machines) can be used to defined [strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_(game_theory)) in game theory. Strategies which can be realized by a transducer are called finite-memory strategies, and when studying a game, an important question is whether it admits a finite-memory optimal strategy (and how to compute it).

Comment: Yes @Nathaniel, but it contained mostly functionalities. I understand how they work. It's just this concept felt a little isolated.

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra, can I encourage you to write that in the 'your answer' box, so this can be treated as answered, and so we can upvote your answer?  The platform works best when people write answers in the 'your answer' area rather than as a comment.  Thank you!

Comment: Well, I didn't consider it detailed enough to make a good answer. But I'll add some more links and post that.

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra, I think it's enough, even without more links!  If you want to add even more, great, but don't let the perfect be the enemy of "good enough". :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moore and Mealy machines are often introduced as a tool for designing digital circuits.
Nice introductions can be found [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-11/finite-state-machines/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3If0Nr9to0).

Answer (score 4):

A prominent and interesting application of transducers, among many others, is to define strategies in game theory. To illustrate this, let me show a few kinds of games and how their strategies differ.

First, *reachability games*. We are given a graph. One vertex is marked as the initial vertex, and some vertices are marked as goal vertices. There is a game token, which starts on the initial vertex. Eve plays against Adam. At their turn, each of the two players moves the token from the current vertex to a vertex which is adjacent on the graph. Eve wants to make the token reach a goal vertex.

A *strategy* for a player is a way for that player to choose the next move based on what happened in the game so far. Reachability games are *determined*, meaning that one of the players always has a *winning strategy*, i.e., a strategy which makes them always win. What is more, reachability games are particularly simple because there is always a *positional* (or *memoryless*) winning strategy, i.e., a strategy where the next move only depends on the current state of the game, and not on the past history of the moves. It's not very hard to convince yourself of this fact: essentially, nothing in the future of the game depends on the past of the game, so there is nothing smarter you can do if you remember the whole history of the game, compared to making a decision just based on the vertex where the token is at the current step.

A toy game to illustrate that this isn't always the case: There is a stack of tokens, and at each turn, the current player adds as many tokens to the stack as they want. The goal of Eve is to ensure that after her turn, there is always a prime number of tokens. This is easy to win for Eve, because for every natural number $n$, there is a prime number greater than $n$. What's interesting about this game, though, is that Eve not only needs to remember things about the past of the game, but if she is playing with a program, that program uses unbounded memory, as it needs to store an arbitrarily large integer. This is called an *infinite-memory* strategy.

Finally, let us return to games on graphs. Now, some vertices of the graph have a treasure, which Eve can collect by moving the token to such a vertex. The goal of Alice is to collect as many treasures as possible. This time, Alice cannot play optimally with a positional strategy. For example, suppose that at the first turn, she makes a move in order to go collect some treasure, she manages to collect it in spite of Adam's adverse moves, and Adam gets the token back to the initial vertex. Now, if she does the same thing that she did on the initial vertex at the beginning, she will go looking for the same treasure again, but it's already been collected, so there is nothing to win anymore. It's smarter to go in another direction to hunt for some other treasure. On the other hand, if Eve plays with a program, that program only needs a finite amount of memory, because all that counts from the history is which treasures have been collected so far. This is called a *finite-memory* strategy.

When studying any class of games, an important question (after proving that winning strategies exist at all) is to determine whether there are positional or finite-memory winning strategies. There are results in game theory which quantitatively study the amount of memory needed to play winning strategies in certain sorts of games.

Now, what's the link with transducers, you ask? Saying that a strategy has finite memory comes down to saying that the strategy can be realized with a transducer. The finite memory is represented by a state structure, which has a token (not the same as the game token for graph-based games) that starts in some predefined state, and each move by the opponent (say, Adam, if this is a strategy for Eve) makes the token take a transition in the state structure. The output of the Moore/Mealy machine at each step is the move that the strategy tells Eve to take.

For more about this topic, see the textbook [Games on Graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.10546.pdf) coordinated by Nathanaël Fijalkow. Memory is defined in section 1.5.

Another example of a game for which winning strategies are finite-memory but usually not positional is the game associated with a non-deterministic Büchi automaton, where Eve chooses successive letters of an infinite word, Adam chooses the transitions to take in the automaton (when there are several choices because of non-determinism), and Eve's goal is to construct a word which is accepted by the automaton with its non-deterministic power, but which Adam doesn't manage to make accepted by choosing transitions as the letters come. This gives rise to the notion of *good-for-games automata*, which has been widely investigated by research in recent years.